# VSCode dart code auto completion doesn't work properly for packages

Tags: flutter, dart, visual-studio-code

I use VSCode for flutter development everything is good but autocompletion is not working properly for packages.I wonder what is wrong with my IDE settings
If I import packages without as keyword the code completion doesn't work but if I import them as something it works for example if I import like following :

```
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart'
```

The intellisense doesn't recognize FireStore and http but if I import like:

```
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart' as fire;
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
```

now when I call fire It shows firestore class and methods and same is for http and every other package

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're not getting auto-suggestions, please check these guidelines

- Please ensure, you have included your package in `pubspec.yaml`
- Did you executed `flutter pub get`
- Usually, we can use **Ctrl+Space** to get auto-suggestion on VSCode

Comment: I've done all of the above suggestions already. sometimes it works by restarting VSCode but most of the time it's not working. if I import as some lib name it works perfectly. I asked the Dart Code contributor in github but still he hasn't answered there

Comment: Usually, I restart VSCode whenever this happens to me! but If you continuously face the same issue, you can try Android Studio

Comment: MacOS using VSCode.

My issue was that import suggestions would not show up.

Ex: import 'mater'
Would not suggest anything. I would expect 'package:flutter/material.dart' to be a suggestion.

Although, now I can press Ctrl+Space to get my suggestions. This must be a setting in some VSCode extension. Not much of a productivity killer, still annoying. Thanks.